# How to fix the drag and drop bug in IE?

Tags: jquery

I am working on the drag and drop element function and have problem on IE.

The dragability works but if I drag my items to the edge of the browser, the contents should be scroll up or down automatically (works in Chrome, FF).
In IE, the element and the dragged element will stock to the edge of the browser without scrolling. Is this IE default behaviors? Are there anyone here can help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these problems will occur and its really hard to debug when you get too far into your code.  Try going to the drag and drop plugin site you and try their demo with IE.  If it works there, then maybe some of your styling or javascript is clashing.  Some workarounds will be upgrading the plugin with the latest release they have.
Other than that, go into their source code and start debugging ;)